# Problem developing a text searcher javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom

I wanted to highlight/style specific words of a text using js.

```
index.html

<body>

    <p id="lorem">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Magni iure doloremque maiores cupiditate quae! 
        Sed dolorum quibusdam ex Lorem vero optio assumenda tenetur iure dolor molestiae, 
        eius eum sequi dolore repellat.
    </p>
    <button onclick="check()">
        check
    </button>

    <script src="./script.js">
    </script>

</body>

script.js

function check(){
  let ipsum = document.getElementById("lorem")
  let vipsum = ipsum.innerHTML

  let elit = vipsum.search(/elit/ig )

  if(elit){
    console.log("so, we have a match")    
    vipsum.substring(elit, 4)

    let highlight = document.querySelector("#lorem").innerHTML[19];
    highlight.style.color: "red"  //Error can't style undefined

  }else{
    console.log("no word matching")
  }

}
```

I can get the matched string in the console but can't style it in the DOM, I wanted to ask if it was possible to do something like this in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can't apply styling to a string you have to apply styling to an html element. When you execute `document.querySelector("#lorem").innerHTML` it returns a string.

One possible solution is to wrap your matched text in an element which can be styled:

```js
function check(){
  let ipsum = document.getElementById("lorem")
  let vipsum = ipsum.innerText

  let matches = vipsum.split(/(elit)/ig)

  if(matches.length > 1){
    console.log("so, we have a match")
    ipsum.innerHTML = matches.map((str, i) => 
       (i % 2) === 1 ? `<span class=highlight>${str}</span>` : str
    ).join('')
  }else{
    console.log("no word matching")
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight {color: red;}
```

```html
<p id="lorem">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
Magni iure doloremque maiores cupiditate quae! 
Sed dolorum quibusdam ex Lorem vero optio assumenda tenetur iure dolor molestiae, 
eius eum sequi dolore repellat.
</p>

<button onclick="check()">check</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works Is the .split() element always an odd index due to the method, or is it something else?

Comment: @MisterlinuZ When splitting a string with a capturing regex there is always an odd number of items in the resulting array. The even indexes (0,2,4,... - first item, third item, ...) are the non-matching bits and the odd indexes are the matches.